# destructing alternatives for hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

For this accordin.js component, why does this line works `setActiveIndex(index);` I thought we assigned things[1] to an object setActiveIndex, then why we're able to call the object setActiveIndex like a function?

```
        import React, { useState } from 'react';

    const Accordion = ( { items }) => {
       // const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(null);
        const things = useState(null);
        const activeIndex = things[0];
        const setActiveIndex = things[1];
        
        const onTitleClick = (index) => {
        console.log('Title clicked', index);
        setActiveIndex(index);
        }
        const renderedItems = items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
        <React.Fragment key={item.title}>
            <div 
            className="title active"
            onClick={  () => onTitleClick(index)}
            >
            <i className="dropdown icon"></i>
                {item.title}
               
            </div>
            <div className="content active">
            <p>{item.content}</p>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>)
        });
        return (<div className="ui styled accordion">
        {renderedItems}
        <h1>{activeIndex}</h1>
        </div>);
    };


    export default Accordion;
```

Comment: [This will help](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The useState hooks returns an array with two elements.
The first element is the current value of that state.
The second element is the function to update the value of the state.

The idiomatic way to write this would be `const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(null)`

In the accordion code `things` is actually an array with the two aforementioned values. Therefore `things[1]` is the function `setActiveIndex`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation for `useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html):

> What does useState return? It returns a pair of values: the current state and a function that updates it. This is why we write `const [count, setCount] = useState()`. This is similar to `this.state.count` and `this.setState` in a class, except you get them in a pair. If you’re not familiar with the syntax we used, we’ll come back to it at the bottom of this page.

AFAIK a more idiomatic version might look like this:

```
 const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(); // null by default if not set
```

That would replace these lines, eliminating `things` entirely:

```
const things = useState(null);
const activeIndex = things[0];
const setActiveIndex = things[1];
```